# How do I send my map to a specific coordinate on Azure maps for Android?

Tags: java, android, azure, azure-maps

So, I have my map all configured, but I can't find the way to center it on a specific coordinate and zoom in. Does anyone know how to do that on Android?

Here is my function where I receive an array with both coordinates.

```
mBtnlocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        double[] coor = new double[2];
        coor = getLastLocation();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the maps `setCamera` function like this:

```
map.setCamera(center(Point.fromLngLat(-122.33, 47.64)), zoom(14));
```

Comment: Ok, thanks man, i was strugling to get that code, apreciated.

Comment: It came from these docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/set-android-map-styles?pivots=programming-language-java-android

Comment: Yes, but it wont acept the zoom call, it says it needs an expression, ive tried everything and nothing works. i can only center the map, but cant zoom in

Comment: That doesn't sound right. But if that's the case try the `literal` expression, like `zoom(literal(14))`

Comment: I figure it out, i just needed to add cameraOptions.zoom(), dont knwo why, but it worked. Thanks